# Scanf Function with Char is Being Skipped in C

Tags: c

I'm new at c programming and I tried to write this basic program below but it keeps skipping the second scanf function(scanf(" %c", &sign)) whatever I do. Do you have any idea to solve this problem? In addition, I tried to use getchar function but it didn't work too.

[SS of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYUJw.jpg)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, mult, sum, subt;
    char sign;

    printf("Enter two numbers: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2);

    printf("\nEnter operator type: ");
    scanf(" %c", &sign);

    if(sign == '*')
        {mult = num1 * num2;
        printf("\nResult is %d\n\n\a", &mult);}

    else if(sign == '+')
        {sum = num1 + num2;
        printf("\nResult is %d\n\n\a", &sum);}

    else if(sign == '-')
        {subt = num1 - num2;
        printf("\nResult is %d\n\n\a", &subt);}

    else
        printf("\nOperator is not valid, program has ended\n\n\a");

system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: post error as a text.

Comment: It would be understandable if there were no space before the `%` in `scanf(" %c", &sign);` but there is. Print the numeric value of `sign` after the input (or with debugger) and also initialise `char sign = 0;` with a known value.

Comment: Enable warnings (`-Wall`) and pay attention to them. You should have got a warning in those printf statements which is an indication that something's wrong there

Comment: Oh - the screen shot shows you *do* enter `'-'` so it does *not* "skip the `scanf`".

Comment: Please replace the screenshot of the error text by the text itself. Just copy&paste it into your question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in these lines

```
printf("\nResult is %d\n\n\a", &mult);
```

```
printf("\nResult is %d\n\n\a", &sum);
```

```
printf("\nResult is %d\n\n\a", &subt);
```

Take off the ampersand `&`. You don't want to print the memory addresses of the variables (which are the large, seemingly random numbers), you want the values stored in the variables.

Comment: Thank you so much, problem has solved thanks to you ^^

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not enabling all warnings.

A good well enabled compiler will warn about:

```
int subt;
printf("\nResult is %d\n\n\a", &subt);}
```

with something like

```
warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]
```

---

To not just solve the little problem, but get to higher level issues, the best things to learn here is to use available resources to help you write error-free code efficiently.

With gcc, consider:

```
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion ..."
```

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks with GNU GCC Compiler but I don't know how I am going to use "-wall" or other commands for this compiler. As I said I'm a newbie at codding, can you please help me about this?

Comment: @DorukOzcan Search on "code block enable all warnings"